# bind compiles but does not get called

Tags: java, bind, javafx

I am trying to bind my print method to xProperty() `(print().bind(scene.xProperty());)`.  It runs once but when the xProperty is called my method doesn't get called again.  How do I get it to call more than once.

```
public DoubleProperty print(){
    System.out.println("print");
    DoubleProperty dp = new DoubleProperty(){
        public void removeListener(ChangeListener cl){}
        public void removeListener(InvalidationListener cl){}
        public void addListener(ChangeListener cl){}
        public void addListener(InvalidationListener cl){}
        public double get(){return 10;}
        public String getName(){return "";}
        public Object getBean(){return new Object();}
        public boolean isBound(){return true;}
        public void unbind(){}
        public void bind(ObservableValue observable){}
        public void set(double d){}
    };
    return dp;

}
```

Comment: whats your goal ? you want to call a method whene ever scene x value changes ?

Comment: Correct.  I figured out how to do it with a change listener. I would like to use bind instead.
 public Chart(Vector<String[]> v, Scene s){
  super();
  this.v = v;
  s.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
   Number old_val, Number new_val) {
    draw();
   }
  });
 }

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for here, but instead of implementing your own DoubleProperty from scratch (Your implementation is missing the proper handling of listeners, for instance) I would suggest to use [SimpleDoubleProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleDoubleProperty.html) as a base.

For example:

```
public class Bean {
    private DoubleProperty print;
    public DoubleProperty printProperty(){
        if (print == null)
            print = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "print");
        return print;
    }
 }
```

Now, you can bind to the print property and register your own listeners on it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not sure how to implement it so it will just call a method.  The example I posted is probably wrong.  I want to be able to call all the methods that I use to draw on a GraphicsContext2D from a Canvas when ever it's parent scene is resized.